# EditText behaves strangely

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my fragment I have two editTexts(xml given below). When the fragment is displayed on the screen, soft keyboard doesn't get visible when I touch the first edit text, I have to  touch the second edit text first which makes the keyboard visible then only I am able to type in first edit text.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/male" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tel" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dad_phone_edt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sansation_regular"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/skype" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dad_skype_edt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sansation_regular"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does the manifest entry for the activity hosting this fragment include any `windowSoftInputMode` attribute?

Comment: no, I have not added this attribute. I don't wan't to dispay the keyboard always I only want to display when there is an edit text. I have some other fragments in the activity which doesn't have any edit text.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to establish it

```
EditText editText= (EditText) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.dad_phone_edt);
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN,0);
                            }
                        });
```

when you click the `editText` you force the keyboard to show

you can do the same for `dad_skype_edt`

to hide the keyboard press back,

if you want to hide it when touch anywhere the layout, add this code

```
your_parent_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
                        if (view != null) {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: make sure OnClickListener is called and working, try changing RESULT_SHOWN with SHOW_FORCED

Comment: onClickListener works. I tried every solution available on the SO but couldn't get it worked. I have same layout as this one in another fragment but keyboard works fine in that, this fragment is loaded after that fragment in app intro library. I think it is the problem in the AppIntro library itself, I have removed that library usage and everything works fine now.